# Change Table Cell Value on hover

Tags: jquery, html

I currently have a table that I need to be able to change the value of a cell on Focus() on that cell and change the value back on Blur().

I have tried http://jsfiddle.net/y41go3td/

```
<table>
     <tr>
       <td>
           <label id="lblname" class="cursor">Hover</label>
       </td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>4</td>
       <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>


var show = function (ev) {
   alert('test');
},
 hide = function (ev) {
     alert('test');
};
$('#lblname').closest('td').focus(show);
$('#lblname').closest('td').blur(hide);
```

but none of the events are fired.

I know there are similar questions all over the web, but none has helped me.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't focus a non-interactive element (inputs, textareas, links etc).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xct5u3qc/1/ ?

Comment: @DavidThomas ya, they need a tabindex attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

```
$('#lblname').closest('td').hover(show, hide);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y41go3td/1/)

```js
var show = function(ev) {
    console.log('test');
  },
  hide = function(ev) {
    console.log('test11');
  };

$('#lblname').closest('td').hover(show, hide);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label id="lblname" class="cursor">Hover</label>
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sure you can make any element focusable and even tabbable: http://jsfiddle.net/xct5u3qc/2/  and tabbable http://jsfiddle.net/xct5u3qc/3/  But because the magic word `Hover` in OP markup, i guess your answer is expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Just put tabindex for the td in the table. It will work.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td tabindex="1">
        <label id="lblname" class="cursor">Hover</label>
    </td>
    <td tabindex="2">1</td>
    <td tabindex="3">2</td>
    <td tabindex="4">3</td>
    <td tabindex="5">4</td>
    <td tabindex="6">5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```